# "Stay on us for this"

Tags: slang, north-american-english

In response to "Thank you. Much appreciated"

Reply was

"Please stay on us for this"

What is the exact meaning of this response.

Comment: Welcome to EL&U. This is a little unclear. If you could possibly provide us with some more context...

Answer (score 1):

I assume the context was:

> You: Can you commit to doing something?
>
> Them: Sure
>
> You: Thank you. Much appreciated.
>
> Them: Please stay on us for this.

This means they want you to track the progress, or at least remind them about this occasionally.